# How to remove the ':' in the datetime format? Python

Tags: python

just as the title states, I had a json file that looks like this:

```
a = {"time": '2017-11-19T03:12:34+0800'}
```

I want to convert it into UTC format and I used the following code:

```
local_time = pytz.timezone("America/New_York")
naive_datetime = datetime.strptime('2017-11-19T03:12:34+0800', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z")
local_datetime = local_time.localize(naive_datetime, is_dst=None)
utc_datetime = local_datetime.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

But this gives me the error:

```
ValueError: time data '2017-11-19T03:12:34+0800' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z'
```

Does anyone know how to remove the ':' in %Z?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a `T` in your time string but a space in your format string.

Comment: That's not the part that doesn't match. The date string has a `T`, and the format has a space in its place.

Comment: A 'cleaner' solution, IMHO, assuming you will follow ISO 8609: use `datetime.fromisoformat()`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat

Answer (score 1):

The correct format string to pass would be using `'%z'` instead of `'%Z'` and replacing your whitepsace with `'T'`

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2017-11-19T03:12:34+0800', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 19, 3, 12, 34, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=28800)))
```